# dbt Macro - Include/exclude field in WHERE clause when does/does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, macros, jinja2, dbt

I'm working in dbt, and I'm new to Jinja and defining macros. I have an `is_deleted_field` that does not exist in every source table that I need to create a snapshot of.

For sources where the `IS_DELETED` field exists, I want the `WHERE` clause to output something like...

```
WHERE 1=1
  AND NOT IS_DELETED
  AND IS_CURRENT
```

...and for sources where the IS_DELETED field does not exist the `WHERE` clause should output...

```
WHERE 1=1
  AND IS_CURRENT
```

But, when I run my current working snapshot for a base model containing the `IS_DELETED` field I get this as well:

```
WHERE 1=1
  AND IS_CURRENT
```

I'm including the working macro for my dbt snapshots below for reference.

```
{% macro snapshot(source_model, is_deleted_field='IS_DELETED', current_only=True) %}

{#
  source_model     | snapshot model ref
  is_deleted_field | name of the field that marks whether a record was deleted
  current_only     | Boolean to include current records (True), or include all history (False)
#}

  SELECT
    {{ dbt_utils.star(from=source_model, except=['DBT_VALID_TO']) }},
    COALESCE(dbt_valid_to, {{ var('constants')['OPEN_END_DATE'] }}) AS dbt_valid_to,
    COALESCE(dbt_valid_to, {{ var('constants')['OPEN_END_DATE'] }}) = {{ var('constants')['OPEN_END_DATE'] }} AS is_current
  FROM
    {{ source_model }}
  WHERE 1=1

    {% if is_deleted_field %}

    AND NOT {{ is_deleted_field }}

    {% elif is_deleted_field.none %}

    NONE

    {% endif %}

    {% if current_only %}

    AND is_current

    {%- endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Can you give two examples of how you're calling the macro, and what arguments you are providing to `is_deleted_field` for the cases where there is or is not such a field?

This macro by itself looks good, except `{% elif is_deleted_field.none %}` should be `{% elif is_deleted_field is none %}` and I don't understand why you would want the literal `NONE` in your query in that case.

Comment: I actually do NOT want the literal NONE in the query. The `IS_DELETED` field contains `true` and `false` values, or the `IS_DELETED` field does not exist entirely. When it doesn't exist, the `WHERE` clause should return `WHERE 1=1 AND IS_CURRENT`.

Comment: Additionally, since it's a dbt snapshot macro it's being called as `{{snapshot(ref('snap_arbitrary_name_here')) }}`. If necessary, I'd love to adjust the macro to account for where `IS_DELETED` does not exist with something like `{{snapshot(ref('snap_arbitrary_name_here'), 'NONE') }}`.